# Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Можно таким образом расставить знаки препинания в предложении: «Объясняется это тем, что с отказом от этого в пользу рыночной экономики, в условиях проводимых в России экономических реформ, значение финансовой деятельности государства — а как результат и регулирующей ее отрасли права — значительно возрастают»?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не стала обособлять *в условиях проводимых в России экономических реформ*

Answer (score 1):

Здесь фразу надо переделывать. В таком виде - хоть обособляй, хоть нет - не понятно, к чему относятся "условия". То ли отказ в условиях реформ, то ли рыночная экономика в условиях реформ, то ли значение возрастает в условиях реформ. А смысл-то несколько разный.

Answer (score 0):

И я о том же: к чему относится противопоставление с союзом "а"? Может, какая-то часть предложения опущена? 
В обособлении действительно нет нужды. Вообще же фраза изрядно вывихнута: "Объясняется ЭТО тем, что с отказом от ЭТОГО".